# How to show sleeping on a slider?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design, sliders

I'm developing an application for a client that asks lots of questions to determine compatibility between people.

Unfortunately, the questions vary greatly, as they can pertain to sleep habits, sports interests, and personality. I find it difficult to display both "spectrums" of whatever the item may be. See the examples below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a clearer way to convey the "range" since the questions don't have a uniform unit?

Comment: Light sleeper/Heavy sleeper isn't a sleeping habit, it's depth of sleep. Try "very light sleeper", "quite a light sleeper", "average sleeper", "quite a heavy sleeper", "very heavy sleeper" and use radio buttons instead, as they do in physiological questionnaires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what this really boils down to is that you are using the wrong control for the job. Most often when designing an interface, if you can't easily map an input to a certain control, it's not the correct control to be using.

In this case while a slider might look more streamlined and attractive, you've noticed their limitation; They exist to choose a value in an easily quantifiable range.

A more apt solution to this problem might be to (like Danny commented) use radio controls instead. Using several preset options removes the confusion the user faces in trying to determine what value exists between two points.